# How to open AsyncTask from a Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, android-asynctask

In my application I have created a `SplashScreen` that will b shown for 5 Seconds and after that it executes an if else case depending upon the values stored in the Preference file. If Preference file contains values then the `AsyncTask` code will run else the Login form will load. When i try to run my application. The thread is going to the Login form with the help of intent but when it comes to `AsyncTask` my application shows a force close error message.

This is my `SplashScreen` code:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

    Thread timer = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                sleep(5000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                if(GoGolfPref.getEmail(SplashScreen.this)!=null && GoGolfPref.getPass(SplashScreen.this)!=null)
                {
                    new LoadingScreen(SplashScreen.this, SplashScreen.this).execute("login_page", Login.url+GoGolfPref.getEmail(SplashScreen.this)+"/"+GoGolfPref.getPass(SplashScreen.this));
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent in = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

}

This is the error I am getting:

```
08-29 07:25:58.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2365): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
08-29 07:25:58.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2365): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
08-29 07:25:58.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2365):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
08-29 07:25:58.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2365):     at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:101)
08-29 07:25:58.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2365):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:63)
08-29 07:25:58.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2365):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:80)
08-29 07:25:58.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2365):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:76)
08-29 07:25:58.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2365):     at com.pnf.gogolf.LoadingScreen.<init>(LoadingScreen.java:130)
08-29 07:25:58.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2365):     at com.pnf.gogolf.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:32)
```

How to get this working?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Nobody wants to wait around 5 seconds for your app to start, this is especially the case for mobile platforms. So just don't do this.

Comment: Agreed with @mimicocotopus - read "Splash screens are evil, don’t use them!" http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=632

Comment: my client wants this splash screen thats why i have to implement it in the application so can you please tell me how to start the runOnUiThread() @mimicocotopus ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're making changes to the UI somewhere, but they're not being done on the UI thread. Anything to do with the user interface has to be done on the UI thread. You do that by encapsulating your code in another runnable and calling runOnUiThread():

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   // set some text views or something
  }
}
```

Comment: can u provide me an example I am new in threads... and how to start this runnable()?

Comment: I am facing the same problem so preferred to ask for some clarification here. Can you please let me know how the final code will look?

Answer (score 2):

Best Practice to use Handler instead of a Thread, because handler can change in UI during the execution
to know more about handler and thread just check this [Handler and Thread in Android](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)